# Problem with __File__ and auto-py-to-exe.exe

Tags: python

The problem is that when i do
`print(__File__)` as a py it outputs `C:/User/.../Desktop/File.py`

BUT when its a exe and i print it it dose this
`print(__File__)` as a exe it outputs `C:/::~1/Temp/_MEI27402/File.py` I want it to output `C:/User/.../Desktop/File.exe`

Yes the _MEI Files dose exist but not the _MEI27402

Comment: It's not going to output what you're looking for, because the code was packed into an exe. When that exe is run, it unpacks the code into a temp location and gives it a temp name. Also, BTW, it's `__file__`, not `__File__`. Capitalization is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

This does play the role of the current running file But from another perspective. And it does work with an executable